# Can I update my research paper before the camera ready date?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, conference

I am trying to finalize the last version of my accepted paper. I have followed the suggestions that I got from the reviewers. While I am editing, I found that a relevant research paper that could benefit my argument if I include it in the related work.

I am just asking if it is ok to extend my reference list (one of the references is self-citation) will it have any bad implications?

Answer (score 6):

I would say the common-sense rule is that minor updates are ok, but major updates - roughly, something that makes it into another paper, or would have required a new peer review - are to be avoided unless explicitly authorized.

Adding a few more sentences mentioning related work is fine, but if you think your changes are significant, describe them in a few (short) sentences and ask the editor/program committee chair.

Also: consult your co-authors before making changes and before requesting authorization for the changes!

Comment: Plus 1. I  would mention and motivate the expansion of the refs list anyway in the resubmission letter.

Comment: @Alchimista: It's not a resubmission, OP is just submitting his camera-ready version.

Comment: Ok. I have not idea of the dictionary used.  For me a resubmission letter accompany the last revised version. Say I would mention that independent of the importance I would assume.